# SpringBoot Application pre-populating data gives error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm writing a REST Api using Spring Boot. This is my User entity.

```
@Entity
public class User extends BaseEntity{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private boolean gender;

    protected User(){
        super();
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, boolean gender) {
        this();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean isGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(boolean gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

This is my Group Entity.

```
@Entity
public class Group extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;

    protected Group(){
        super();
    }

    public Group(String name) {
        this();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Currently they have no mapped relationship. When I create an application loader for the User Entity it works fine but the same for Group doesn't work.

```
@Component
public class DataBaseLoader implements ApplicationRunner {

    private final UserRepository users;
    private final GroupRepository groups;

    @Autowired
    public DataBaseLoader(UserRepository users, GroupRepository groups) {
        this.users = users;
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

        User user = new User("Adam", "Smith", null, true);
        users.save(user);
        Group group = new Group("Philly Billies");
        groups.save(group);

    }
}
```

> Thus in this class if I comment out the Group items the application
>   runs fine.

This is the error log.

```
2016-07-06 14:29:30.713 ERROR 1516 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at io.soumasish.Application.main(Application.java:14) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:473) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

2016-07-06 14:29:30.719  INFO 1516 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-07-06 14:29:30.725 ERROR 1516 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:165) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at io.soumasish.Application.main(Application.java:14) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:159) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted

2016-07-06 14:29:30.726  INFO 1516 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/Sites/JavaDrive/Projects/BB-RestApi/build/classes/main/, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest/1.3.3.RELEASE/39aa9031c0e628da6ccb5ee15ac0923c63306dcd/spring-boot-starter-data-rest-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.3.3.RELEASE/c1f8f3102650e54259d69c519b45b64fbf5cd25b/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.h2database/h2/1.4.191/dec3540178ea889b2871b0ed56db14bbec9cfdfc/h2-1.4.191.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.3.RELEASE/e4a71ce6ae8e42a7535dd9f1a39f91d36c538f28/spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.3.RELEASE/f1ee2657f50844d8682b30a1f40aebff3ad60cce/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.6.5/65137ebf85056473b40c311f889601646a7612ba/jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.6.5/d50be1723a09befd903887099ff2014ea9020333/jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-webmvc/2.4.4.RELEASE/41c0fad87f74df36b3b4167f699523a0d505acd0/spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.4.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.3.RELEASE/f80c290f6a3dccb8255a594795a20048c63460da/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.3.RELEASE/f10ffeca4c879f1f66f30989cc0f133258934246/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/27a119fcc2b91c50e5285dd11158fac2c38c9d1b/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/d81aff979d603edd90dcd8db2abc1f4ce6479e3e/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.4.RELEASE/80b83510e67aa085b7d91d2d096d90133ec995de/spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.5.RELEASE/ed09517441a276db2a7e0e7b60a390c52b8093af/spring-aspects-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.3.3.RELEASE/641cc375499d444e4efbc1801902260daa79758d/spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.3.RELEASE/e7a4a25f74dac6b335ffabc43e3e8a6e3066340e/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.3.RELEASE/16b395c84f28b947f1c336aa461fda1e662bb3b6/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/251207b29f0f38f61e3495a2f7fb053cf1bfe8c/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/d64fb662c9e42789149f5078a62a22edda786c6a/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.3.RELEASE/541468d85cc2c94d2b538b0fa07c018847bb9b78/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.3.RELEASE/df2d5a437fa3093b8da99216c355189fe7b5e64/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/4.2.5.RELEASE/49cd2430884b77172aa81e3fc33ef668ea1dab30/spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.5.RELEASE/cf463cce3e4453eb4b9a69de2dcdfd60c3c57e0/spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.6.5/334369d7eff497f358b248c171dac0dd62c68f67/jackson-core-2.6.5.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-core/2.4.4.RELEASE/a770ecceb87de091f60d920e3dedfeed3f79088b/spring-data-rest-core-2.4.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.fge/json-patch/1.7/78831bdcabc64a4f9e64e1439763010b24e0d71d/json-patch-1.7.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/3a6274f658487d5bfff9af3862beff6da1e7fd52/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.16/34e48073884704ac987d3d1a1ab9b60e62028a9/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.2.5.RELEASE/858d6c70909b3ce7e07b59fc936f8ccfcd81c0aa/spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.8/969c8d3d3d56db1e1c8721a03ef07d0c9ac3a2e4/aspectjweaver-1.8.8.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.32/55396c45fc8c34f31420a3b280fde4b1387b044d/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.5.RELEASE/205d2f1b902eac16a2ece772dc5ac6090b7e0b6f/spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/3616bb87707910296e2c195dc016287080bba5af/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/2f437f37bb265d9f8f1392823dbca12d2bec06d6/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/536ac0021240d97db99c7d2983067cef1a6f3af5/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/5d3ccc056b6f056dbf0dddfdf43894b9065a8f94/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/2a581b9edb8168e45060d8bad8b7f46712d2c52c/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/5e731d961297e5a07290bfaf3db1fbc8bbbf405a/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/d9a09f7732226af26bf99f19e2cffe0ae219db5b/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/1.11.4.RELEASE/c2b1fd4dbf7dff772d6124bb35892759e8bf088e/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.2.5.RELEASE/60625981b837ba93e603d3068d69c6397ecb3ad2/spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/4.2.5.RELEASE/a75e18322c7b362fe1daa26a245ae672ec0f3138/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/4.2.5.RELEASE/7395321fe937272d9b781a13985e04ab2dcd6210/spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.2.5.RELEASE/fa992ae40f6fc47117282164e0433b71da385e94/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.5/92353eb144695bba80b31f7bec4f36d871f230ac/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.16/2d5b546c5557dcbf08c3a381d7dc9bd275a602c1/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.16/c5922f37c8a5e4377cfb543c549f10e73d72ede0/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.32/734ead0c803525cc9c7f283438101734ca9aac01/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.32/82adf8bd959fc046d55490e6f2ce67297c91d62b/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.32/5e664b357710a6c43cad2191404c2a9d0b82cdb3/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.32.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.32/237ca58dac66f438579750169e6cb297ac041c9d/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/fb18766b576aa6632bcfe9a20a023cbd52bf9769/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/4.2.5.RELEASE/a42bdfb833d0be6c18429aea3fb0fba81f85c6e8/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.hateoas/spring-hateoas/0.19.0.RELEASE/77b3b15c301d2517356b76304a2670df33ef2e2c/spring-hateoas-0.19.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/f380e7760032e7d929184f8ad8a33716b75c0657/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.atteo/evo-inflector/1.2.1/b9cdd1e7dc20a222db0853dfb152ef349c7d0eed/evo-inflector-1.2.1.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.fge/jackson-coreutils/1.6/9e6af56eb7cc2a65700b289abc7ee2bd170fd231/jackson-coreutils-1.6.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/516c03b21d50a644d538de0f0369c620989cd8f0/jsr305-2.0.1.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/235ba8b489512805ac13a8f9ea77a1ca5ebe3e8/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.32/71471069cea029dfdce0735337864c7d0a3d9992/tomcat-juli-8.0.32.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/e84a2122e76f0b6503be78094ddf2108057ac15f/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/3136ca936f64c9d68529f048c2618bd356bf85c9/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.1.5/16722afde74444716e299bee1f60aec9f6d1f0dc/logback-core-1.1.5.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/8613ae82954779d518631e05daa73a6a954817d5/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/dbbd699a1486ad0f2ed6f5af6cfed66acacb9056/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.fge/msg-simple/1.1/f261263e13dd4cfa93cc6b83f1f58f619097a2c4/msg-simple-1.1.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/16.0.1/5fa98cd1a63c99a44dd8d3b77e4762b066a5d0c5/guava-16.0.1.jar, file:/Users/Soumasish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.fge/btf/1.2/9e66651022eb86301b348d57e6f59459effc343b/btf-1.2.jar, file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The error log and the problem you've described don't match up. As @matsev said in their answer, the error is showing that port 8080 is in use. That won't be affected by JPA. Can you share the Group-related failure?

Comment: Probably you have another process running in the same port, one in run mode another debug mode

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you already have a process running on port 8080 (perhaps the same Spring Boot app that was started earlier)?

Copied from the stack trace:

> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
>   [...]
>
> Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Comment: I restarted this isn't the issue.

Comment: I've updated the question slightly highlighting the core problem.